# Design decision for a Java EE 6 (EJB, JSF, CDI, JPA) application

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, cdi, ejb-3.1

I am developing a small (but growing) Java EE project based on the technologies EJB 3.1, JSF 2, CDI (WELD) and JPA 2 deployed on a JBOSS AS 7.1Beta1.

As a starting point I created a Maven project based on the Knappsack Maven archetypes.

My architecture is basically the same provided by the archetype and as my project grows I think this archetype seems to be reaching its limits. I want to modify the basic idea of the archetype according to my needs. But let me first explain how the project is organized at the moment.

The whole project is built around Seam like Home classes. The view is referencing them (via EL in xhtml templates). Most of the Home classes are `@Named` and `@RequestScoped` (or shortly `@Model`) or `@ConversationScoped` and Entripse Java Beans are `@Inject`ed. Basically these (normally `@Local`) EJBs are responsible for the database access (Some kind of DAOs) to get transactions managed automatically by the container. So every DAO class has its own [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) injected via CDI. At the moment every DAO integrates aspects which logically belong to each other (e. g. there is a `SchoolDao` in the archetype which is responsible for creating `Teacher`s, `Student`s and `Course`s).

This of course results in growing DAOs which have no well defined task and which become hard to maintain and hard to understand. And as a painful side effect the risk of duplicate code grows.

As a consequence I want to breakup this design by having only DAOs which are responsible for one specific task (a `@StudentDao`, a `@TeacherDao`and so on). And at this point I am in trouble. As each DAO has a reference to its own `EntityManager` it cannot be guaranteed that something like the following will work (I think it never will :)

```
Teacher teacher = teacherDao.find(teacherId);
course.setTeacher(teacher);
courseDao.save(course);
```

The JPA implementaion complains about a `null` value for column `COURSE.TEACHER_ID` (assuming `Course` has a not nullable FK realtionship to `Teacher`). Each DAO holds its own `EntityManager`, the `teacher` is managed by the one in the `TeacherDao`, but the other one in the `CourseDao` tries to merge the `Course` `@Entity`.

Maybe the archetye I used is not suitable for larger applications. But what would be a appropriate design for such an aplication then IF the technologies I used are obligatory (EJB 3.1 for container managed transactions [and later on other business related stuff], JSF as view technologie, JPA as the database mapper and CDI as the 'must have because it's hip:)?

Edit:

I now have an `EntityManager` injected in the base class all other DAO classes inherit from. So all DAOs use the same instance (debugger shows same object id) but I still have the problem that all entities that I read from the database are immediately detached. This is something that makes me wonder as it means that there is either no container managed transaction or the transaction gets immediately closed after the entity was read. Each DAO is a `@Local` `@Stateless` EJB. They are injected into my JSF Beans (`@Named` and `@RequestScoped`) from where I want to make use of the CRUD operations. Is there anything I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Having each DOA have its own `EntityManager` is a very bad design.

You should have an `EntityManager` per transaction/request and pass it to each DOA, or have them share the same one or get it from the context.

Comment: I now have an `EntityManager` injected in the base class all other DAO classes inherit from. So all DAOs use the same instance (debugger shows same object id) but I still have the problem that all entities that I read from the database are immediately detached. See edited question...